# Flash policy request C

Tags: c, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a server for a flash game in C, however I am having problems with the "flash policy" part.

This is my policy string:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="1-31111" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Connection send code + flash policy rule:

```
char toSend[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\r\n<cross-domain-policy>\r\n<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"1-31111\" />\r\n</cross-domain-policy>\0"; /* some string */
write(connfd, &toSend,  sizeof(toSend));
```

Seems to be working, but sadly it closes the connection and printing some zero incomming values out:

```
Server running...waiting for connections.
Received request...
Incoming packet: <policy-file-request/>
Received request...
Incoming packet: 
Incoming packet:
```

Thank you

Comment: In your string, take note " and ” are different characters. You have extra space in "permitted-cross-domain- policies". Are you sure you are parsing server response (XML) in a right way?

Comment: Updated code. Can someone please put the code inside the code tag? Not working for me here.

Comment: I did it again. You were missing new line before code text.

Comment: Again, how do you parse server response in your client code? Can you put that code here?

Comment: With while ( (n = recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE,0)) > 0)  { }

Comment: Do you consider that socket bytes can be sent in chunks?

Comment: Trace incoming bytes or buffer length, and check if you got full policy string length, when you do, then parse it.

Comment: Also, it is normal for Flash player to disconnect after reading policy file, and using policy rules, makes a new connection. Check "What data is sent in the request and response?" at:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The new output is Error: Invalid message length in the console log of chrome. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, that is another question now...